# The number of soldiers each house can rally

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

Now that we might see some Vale action, I really wonder the number of soldiers each house can muster. There is a comprehensive semi-canon source for this question: http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Armies

However, I am seeking a canon answer. By canon, I mean the books (*A Song of Ice and Fire*) first. The series (*Game of Thrones*) are also welcome if they do not directly contradict with the books. I am seeking information of the following sort:

- The Northern host was about 20000-25000 when they leave Moat Cailin.
- Rodrik Cassel gathered more than 2000 when Winterfell was invaded by Theon.
- They were attacked by about 400 soldiers from Dreadfort.
- Stannis had about 2500-3000 soldiers from the mountain clans.

So, the North must have around 25000-30000 soldiers at the least.

We have some direct information as well: Dorne called her banners and mustered 50000 spears, according to the books. The Twins had 4000 soldiers.

Do we have canon information, similar to what I have provided for the rest of the great houses and the Crownlands? <s>Great or small houses are welcome.</s>

Comment: The source for question is most likely where we would get our answers. The ASOIAF wiki is already sourcing the books and is giving all the detail there is.

Comment: @Skooba I have been digging ASOIAF wiki for days. Unfortunately not all the information is in there. The best they can offer is the semi-canon information. Moreover, with the series going ahead of the books, they received some canonicity. :)

Comment: This seems a little broad to me...  "Great or small, or houses are welcome." Perhaps refine the question to ask about the total military population of Westeros (ie the sum of Westerosi armies is x number of men)or about a specific house?

Comment: @kuhl I have refined the question as you suggested.

Comment: Some info can be found in: [What is the military strength of the Vale?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/72528/21267), [In ACOK, how large was each of the armies?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/56894/21267), [Where do soldiers in Westeros come from?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/65328/21267) and [How many people actually died during The War of the Five Kings?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/107687/21267)

Comment: There's basically not much we can add besides the points you've already addressed. Unless you asked GRRM directly (and even then he doesn't like giving accurate numbers necessarily).

Comment: @C.Koca Just out of interest, are we musing about military strengths at start of War of Five Kings or are we thinking about military strengths at end of ADWD?

Comment: The start of the war was my primary intention.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**About 15-30 thousand troops each.**

It depends on the House, the war, number of sell-swords available and the current conditions, but in general, as you noted in your question, most of the Great Houses can field roughly 15 to 30 thousand men.

See also:

- [What is the military strength of the Vale?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/56923/21267)
- [In ACOK, how large was each of the armies?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/56894/21267)
- [Where do soldiers in Westeros come from?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/65328/21267)

It's not very important to the story **exactly** how many men were fielded by each army; only that they matched with most differences being minor ones. Some had more horses, some more spearmen, etc.

The point of talking about massive armies was to give a sense of the scale, as well as to highlight the tactics used within the battles.

For examply, Robb Stark's army was outnumbered by Tywin's, yet he used his cunning to overcome them in his battles.

The author, George R. R. Martin, has said on multiple occasions that he likes to keep exact details such as dates, timelines, numbers and distances intentionally vague. It is hard to keep up with, and also doesn't necessarily add a huge amount to the plot.

Comment: This answer is partly wrong, because we certainly know that Highgarden and Dorne can field much more soldiers than the rest. However, keeping in mind that as commented above, the information I am seeking for may not even exist. Also, you are right about GRRM keeping such details vague, as it takes too much effort to write a consistent seven volume book without any contradiction. My final point is that as you suggested, the rest of the great houses are probably around the same scale and a rough 15-30k seems reasonable. So you have my thanks and upvote.

Comment: @C.Koca Yes, I was going to mention that some houses can field more men, but then I thought it's not important.